# How to select/activate a worksheet from word-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, multiple-monitors

I use two screen monitors. The left monitor has an Excel Workbook opened. The right monitor has a Microsoft Word document opened. I use a Word Userform to bring data from the opened workbook to the opened Word document.

But sometimes I need to change the activated/selected worksheet (I mean, the one that is in front of the others; th3e one I can see), and I would like to do so from a button in my Microsoft Word userform.

The code below does not work, and I have no idea how to achieve that goal.

Please, would someone have an idea how to achieve that?

```
Sub ACTIVATE_WORKSHEET_ASDF()

Dim MyExcel As Excel.Application
Dim MyWB As Excel.Workbook
Set MyExcel = New Excel.Application
Set MyWB = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("MY EXCEL WORKBOOK FULL PATH")
Dim ASDF As Worksheet
Set ASDF = MyWB.Sheets("ASDF")

ASDF.Select 'DO NOT WORK
ASDF.Activate 'DO NOT WORK
Debug.Print ASDF.Cells(1,1) 'DOES WORK!

MyWB.Close False
Set MyExcel = Nothing
Set MyWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You are creating a new Excel instance. It works, but remains invisible. You then close it. If you want to connect to an existing instance, use [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am glad to know it is possible! But since it is not as straightforward as I was expecting, for now I will stick to a very simple AutoIt macro executed from my word Userform, that simulates mouse moves and mouse clicks. Thank you again!!

Comment: @strajano - `GetObject` is pretty straightfoward and is much better than mouse moves and clicks.

Comment: Thanks BigBen! Your words encouraged me a lot to try. When I saw 32 bit API reference in the code, and I remembered my Excel is 64 bits, then I felt a little intimidated. But in one week or so I will have more free time to do my research and modify my macros to the GetObject paradigm!! The AutoIt solution is going to be only temporary solution. Have a great day!!